# Scalability considerations in web applications

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have posted a similar question before and it was marked as too broad, so I will try to narrow this down. I have been building web applications for a few years. Mostly java web apps using spring mvc, jquery/ajax front end, jpa persistence tier, with dao patterns, etc.

I've seen alot of job openings for experience with scalable and high traffic web apps. My question is when developing the server side application code (lets say a Spring controller for example), what are some considerations that may be made when building the controller code for an application that has 100,000 users, vs one that has 50 users?

I'm not sure that I understand what some characteristics of an app designed for high traffic or scalability would have that a traditional application wouldn't, outside of caching potentially. Any good resources?

Comment: I have been building websites for many years too. How I understand it is that you build the web application to be as efficient as possible. Then for handling large number of concurrent sessions you need to use clustering architecture. E.g. Web server farm and cluster the database servers and so on. You can do so much in the application but end of the day, it's the hardware that getting max out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of features about scalable, high-traffic, highly-available server side applications:

- involve as little shared state between the client and server as possible - anything which ties a client to a node is a killer. This is why ReST has become so popular in recent years.
- all layers of your infrastructure must be scalable and highly available - databases, caches, load-balancers, data-centers. It's not just your application core.
- distribute across data centres, across the globe.
- operational concerns are important. If you scale your application over 20 or more globally distributed nodes how are you monitoring them? Capturing logging and performance data and monitoring system performance is crucial. Remember to capture and monitor both service metrics and node metrics.
- automate deployment - when you need to scale up you'll probably need to do it *quickly*. Manual deployment is just not scalable.
- remember the [CAP theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) - you can't have the utopian goal of consistency, availability and partition-tolerance in a distributed system. You need to design your application so that it doesn't implicitly depend on the CAP theorem being false.

*If* you keep yourself aware of all that and find yourself following best practice, then individual node performance generally becomes less of an issue - you scale horizontally, by adding new nodes, rather than vertically, by squeezing more performance from your available CPU cycles.